# StackOverflowException on PubNub Subscribe

Tags: c#, pubnub

I am trying to use the PubnubPCL package off of Nuget to subscribe, however whenever this function is called, the program exits with a StackOverflow exception, about 2 seconds after. Here is the exact same code that causes the error. I am completely baffled on why this is happening because I use pretty much the exact same code in a different program. This one function seemingly is the only cause to the StackOverflow exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PubnubApi;

namespace PubnubTest
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub(new PNConfiguration(){ SubscribeKey = "<removed>", ReconnectionPolicy = PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR });

            pubnub.AddListener(new SubscribeCallbackExt(
                (pubnubObj, message) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                },
                (pubnubObj, presence) => { Console.WriteLine(presence.ToString()); },
                (pubnubObj, status) => {
                    if (status.Category == PNStatusCategory.PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] Pubnub unexpectedly disconnected.");
                    }
                    else if (status.Category == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[LOG] Pubnub successfully connected.");
                    }
                    else if (status.Category == PNStatusCategory.PNReconnectedCategory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[LOG] Pubnub reconnecting...");
                    }
                    else if (status.Category == PNStatusCategory.PNDecryptionErrorCategory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] Could not decrypt recieved message.");
                    }
                    else if (status.Category == PNStatusCategory.PNBadRequestCategory)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] An unexpected error occurred.");
                    }
                }
            ));

            pubnub.Subscribe<string>()
             .Channels(new string[] {
                 "<removed>"
             }).WithPresence()
             .Execute();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills I set a breakpoint, the program stackoverflows as soon as the pubnub.Subscribe method is called. If I comment out the line, it doesn't error.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry about that. The function was moved around a bit while debugging. The subscribe key and channel name was supposed to be fed to the function from the parameter, but during testing I changed it to hardcoded values. Anyway the issue was fixed by downgrading to an earlier version of Pubnub, not sure if it's an issue with my code or a bug in the new version, but it works now.

Comment: @mjwills The code was modified to use a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. The code works in the 4.0.16 version of PubnubPCL found on Nuget, however crashes with a StackOverflow Exception on the other tested version of 4.0.20.

Comment: @jake, post your fix as an answer and select it as accepted.

Comment: @Jake - our engineers were unable to reproduce this. Can you provide the full error stack trace and the target platform you are using with PubNubPCL?